# Incomplete Provenance Capture in JOBS Database After Upgrading MarkLogic, DHF, and Java Client API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-11

Below are the details of the upgrades we performed :

|  | MarkLogic | DHF | Gradle | mlcp/XCC | Java Client API | ml-javaclient-util |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Before | 10.0-9.2 | 5.2.0 | 5.2.1 | 9.0.8/9.0.7 | 4.2.0 | 3.13.3 |
| After | 11.1.0 | 5.8.1 | 6.4 | 11.0.3 | 6.3.0 | 4.6.0 |

Post the upgrade we have encountered a persisting issue with the JOBS database. Currently, it fails to capture complete step details. Specifically, it only retains information for the step currently executing, overwriting the data of the previous step as soon as the subsequent step begins.

It is working fine in the environments where the upgrades have not yet been done.

Below are the to sample provenance files:

1. Post upgrade:

   ```
   "job": {
       "jobId": "d109d96c-9020-44f0-8f84-5fb711eb1420/2023-28/2024-01-18T18:53:25.865",
       "flow": "*********",
       "user": "*********",
       "lastAttemptedStep": "14",
       "lastCompletedStep": "14",
       "jobStatus": "finished",
       "timeStarted": "2024-01-18T22:24:47.394379+01:00",
       "stepResponses": {
           "14": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "targetEntityType": "MatchingResult",
               "targetDatabase": "***-data-hub-STAGING",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 14",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2024-01-18T22:24:47.423718+01:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2024-01-18T22:27:27.983826+01:00"
           }
       },
       "timeEnded": "2024-01-18T22:27:28.018498+01:00"
   }
   ```

}```

2. Before upgrade

   ```
   "job": {
       "jobId": "6d3be8aa-062f-4d6d-8d56-d313ca18b1c9/2023-24/2023-06-26T08:52:24.884",
       "flow": "*********",
       "user": "*********",
       "lastAttemptedStep": "14",
       "lastCompletedStep": "14",
       "jobStatus": "finished",
       "timeStarted": "2023-06-26T10:52:27.087495+02:00",
       "timeEnded": "2023-06-26T11:25:36.168996+02:00",
       "stepResponses": {
           "1": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 1",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T10:52:27.13748+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T10:52:32.374773+02:00"
           },
           "2": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 2",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T10:52:32.505048+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T10:52:55.896385+02:00"
           },
           "3": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 3",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T10:52:56.025055+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T10:53:13.547117+02:00"
           },
           "4": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 4",
               "totalEvents": 2497,
               "successfulEvents": 22497,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 225,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T10:53:13.683279+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:02.097445+02:00"
           },
           "5": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 5",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:02.894001+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:25.212723+02:00"
           },
           "6": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 6",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:25.335696+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:25.564489+02:00"
           },
           "7": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 7",
               "totalEvents": 11,
               "successfulEvents": 15011,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 151,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:10:25.650559+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:18:10.419283+02:00"
           },
           "8": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 8",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:18:11.105034+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.197125+02:00"
           },
           "9": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 9",
               "totalEvents": 0,
               "successfulEvents": 0,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 0,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.310099+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.416497+02:00"
           },
           "10": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 10",
               "totalEvents": 0,
               "successfulEvents": 0,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 0,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.567946+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.64965+02:00"
           },
           "11": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 11",
               "totalEvents": 0,
               "successfulEvents": 0,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 0,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:04.868482+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:05.022998+02:00"
           },
           "12": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 12",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:05.179518+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:56.693317+02:00"
           },
           "13": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 13",
               "totalEvents": 635,
               "successfulEvents": 635,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 7,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:19:56.816666+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:22:04.559349+02:00"
           },
           "14": {
               "flowName": "*********",
               "stepName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionName": "*********",
               "stepDefinitionType": "custom",
               "stepOutput": null,
               "fullOutput": null,
               "status": "completed step 14",
               "totalEvents": 1,
               "successfulEvents": 1,
               "failedEvents": 0,
               "successfulBatches": 1,
               "failedBatches": 0,
               "success": true,
               "stepStartTime": "2023-06-26T11:22:04.716391+02:00",
               "stepEndTime": "2023-06-26T11:25:36.095889+02:00"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

}```

Steps are functioning correctly. Additionally, post-DHF upgrade, we noticed new modules introduced, including:

- /data-hub/5/data-services/job/startJob.sjs
- /data-hub/5/data-services/job/startStep.sjs
- /data-hub/5/data-services/job/finishStep.sjs
- /data-hub/5/data-services/job/finishJob.sjs
- /data-hub/5/data-services/job/getJob.sjs

Do any modifications need to be made to these modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this as MarkLogic Support has confirmed that this is expect behaviour.